# Site redirects to wrong url when saving settings

Tags: redirect, htaccess, directory, subdomains, site-url

I have a subdomain:

```
https://blog.example.com/
```

I forcibly redirects to subdirectory:

```
https://www.example.com/blog
```

By changing site URL and some `RewriteRule` on `.htaccess`.

Now the website and admin works fine except a small issue like when I tried to click save button on settings page (eg: *Setting > Writing* ) the site redirects to main domain:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-admin/options-writing.php?settings-updated=true
```

`/blog` is missing in the URL and end up in to main website 404 page.

My .htaccess file looks like :

```
    # BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Host}i ^example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Server}i !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Server}i !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]


RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

When click save button, console have an error message:

```
/wp-admin/options-general.php?settings-updated=true:1 GET https://www.example.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?settings-updated=true 404 ()
```

Can anybody help to figure this out?

Updated working .htaccess (according to 1st answer) :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
```

My wordpress address and site address are:

```
WordPress Address (URL) =   /blog
Site Address (URL) = https://www.example.com/blog
```

Comment: What `RewriteRule` are you using in your `.htaccess`? Please [`edit`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/239938/edit) your question with the rules you are using.

Comment: @EthanJinksO'Sullivan : Thanks for help. I updated the question with .htaccess content.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your `.htaccess`, it looks like your has too many rules overlapping each other. Do the following instead:

1. Keep a backup of your current `.htaccess` if you need to go back to it
2. Delete your `.htaccess` form the server, WordPress should automatically create a fresh one for you
3. Open your new `.htaccess` file and add the following between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tag:

.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Your `.htaccess` should then look like the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Custom rewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: When I delete my current .htaacess and tried with yours, then I open website shows too many redirects. So I replace old .htaccess file. I should have to write rules for **1) non https -> https  2) subdomain -> sub directory** .  I noticed one thing that when I open console in wp-admin page I found an error : _Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://blog.example.com/wp-admin/index.php' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://www.example.com' and URL 'https://www.example.com/blog/wp-admin/index.php'._

Comment: My updated .httaccess: `# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Host}i ^example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/blog/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
`

Comment: When I dig more in to the console error, found the line causing error is: `window.history.replaceState( null, null, document.getElementById( 'wp-admin-canonical' ).href + window.location.hash );`